# PyMongo: "not authorized on db to execute command" but roles and credentials are ok

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have two users, *admin* and *user*.

```
use admin
db.getUser('admin')
{
  _id: 'admin.admin',
  userId: UUID("xx"),
  user: 'admin',
  db: 'admin',
  roles: [
    { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' }
  ],
  mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
}
use mydb
db.getUser('user')
{
  _id: 'mydb.user',
  userId: UUID("xx"),
  user: 'user',
  db: 'mydb',
  roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'mydb' } ],
  mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
}
```

If I log in as *user* using mongosh or MongoDB Compass I can totally do any read or write queries, but if I try anything using a PyMongo cursor:

```
r = list(mongo.db.mycollection.find())
```

I get:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on db to execute command { find: "mycollection", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("xx") }, $db: "db", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'not authorized on db to execute command { find: "config", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("xx") }, $db: "db", $readPreference: { mode: "primaryPreferred" } }', 'code': 13, 'codeName': 'Unauthorized'}
```

But if I do the same using admin instead everything is ok.

My guesses are that it authenticates but does not get inside the specified database, it probably reaches some other default database instead and that's why it says it has not authorization (despite I specified it in the URI).

Here is my URI:

```
mongodb://user:passwd@localhost:27017/mydb?authSource=mydb&readPreference=primary&appname=myapp&ssl=false
```

Any ideas how to debug my issue?

Comment: In `mongosh`, where everything works fine, what is `db.getMongo()`?  Is it different than the URI above?

Comment: The query seems to be executed on database `db` instead of `mydb`, see error message *{ find: "mycollection", filter: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("xx") }, **$db: "db"**, ... 'code': 13, 'codeName': 'Unauthorized'}*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess python runs some additional queries in background.

From MongoDB documentation:

> Roles which are created in **other** database than `admin` can only include privileges that apply to its database and can only inherit from other roles in its database.
>
> A role created in the `admin` database can include privileges that apply to **any** database or to the cluster resource, and can inherit from roles in other databases as well as the `admin` database.

I would suggest to create the user in `admin` database and grant roles accordingly:

```
db.getSiblindDB("admin").createUser( { 
   user: "user",
   pwd: "<password>"
   roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "mydb" }] 
})
```

Comment: It was a good idea. I tried adding the roles "dbAdmin" and "dbOwner" to mydb inside the admin collection, sadly didn't work. I tested my credentials by adding the role "readwriteAnyDatabase" to `user` and that does work, but would defeat the purpose :(

Comment: Again, according to the error message you try to access database `db` - not `mydb`. Check your code.

Comment: You are totally right. I used to access my database as mongo.db.mycol in flask_pymongo, but since I switched to pure pymongo I have use mongo.mydb.mycol instead.